# What does 'pluralist' mean, for 'community councils'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

Source: p 439, *Urban Geography, A Global Perspective* (3 ed, 2009) by Michael Pacione

> [...] Similar
>   criticisms may be directed at the system of community
>   councils introduced in British cities[,] as a means of
>   ascertaining and conveying the views of local communities
>   to relevant public bodies. Interpreted in **pluralist**
>   terms, community councils represent a widening of
>   political accessibility, but this is taking place within
>   constraints set from above. A structuralist perspective
>   would emphasise the lack of any real delegation of
>   power[,] to the local level[;]
>   and view the scheme as a useful
>   means of social control[,]    by which grass-roots pressure
>   for social change may be diverted into a concern
>   with social justice.
>
> [[ODO:]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pluralism) 1.4. {Philosophy} A theory or system that recognizes more than one ultimate principle. Compare with [monism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/monism).

Did I guess the correct definition of **pluralist**? Even if so, what does it mean in this context?

Comment: All four sub-definitions of 1.0 have the same basic idea; that basic idea is the meaning here.

Comment: Somebody downvoted. Personally I think this is a great question. There's evidence of research and an attempt to understand the problem. The context is quoted. There's a link to the definition.

Comment: I am downvoting because this is general reference. Type the words "political pluralism" into Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the list of definitions you linked, it would be definition 1.2:

> A theory or system of devolution and autonomy for individual bodies in preference to monolithic state control.

The community councils give more power to local communities, so that results in greater "autonomy for individual bodies". The other perspective mentioned, the structuralist perspective, would represent "monolithic state control".

See [Structural Pluralism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pluralism) and [Pluralism (political theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralism_%28political_theory%29).

Note that *all* the definitions at Oxford Dictionaries share a common idea of there being many things, rather than just one.